pandas cannot set a value for MultiIndex
It is not allowed to set a value for a MultiIndex. It works for the single index. Maybe becaause of the version of pandas.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.loc[('a', 'b'), 'col1'] = 1
print(df)


KeyError: "None of [Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"


You can do either
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([], names=['level_1', 'level_2'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1'], index=index)

df.loc[('a', 'b'), 'col1'] = 1

print(df)

or
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1'], index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[], []], codes=[[], []], names=['level_1', 'level_2']))

df.loc[('a', 'b'), 'col1'] = 1

print(df)


which returns

                col1
level_1 level_2     
a       b          1

